# Is "fine" one of the strangest words in English language? How did it come to be this way and are there other examples?

Tags: etymology, adjectives

Many words have multiple meanings but not many words have different meanings in the same context. Fine can mean both very good-to-excellent and acceptable but probably below average. For example, the phrase "that is a fine retelling of the story". Which version of fine is meant? You only really know based upon the context of what is used. Are there examples of other words like this?

**Edit 1:** As an example, as an undergrad I went to a school with narrative evaluations. As a student, you'd write a paper. If the prof would say, "You used good examples — a fine paper" it would mean acceptable. "You used very good examples — a fine paper"; it would mean exemplary (somewhat implying that 'very good' is understating it.

Comment: Very few words are unlike it. Nearly any word in the English language assumes subtle difference of implication from the context, the tone, the speaker/ author, the works. *Fine* is a fine example, though, but nothing much special in this respect.

Comment: If the speaker said, "fine retelling of the story," I would immediately think, in print, that it was good-to-excellent. If the other listeners knew that it was a terrible rendition, then they would understand that the speaker were simply being kind. There are prosody stresses that cue the native listener to the speaker's intent. Here's a different example: "Fat chance" and "slim chance" both mean that the speaker thinks there's little possibility of something occurring. http://askville.amazon.com/fat-chance-slim-thing/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=6974145

Comment: Some words seem to have different (perhaps to the point of opposite) new meanings thrust upon them (gay; wicked) whereas many others are used antiphrastically on occasion for sarcastic or comic effect ('That's nice, that is!' Tommy Cooper).

Comment: @Kris I appreciate the irony of your last sentence :-) But I disagree because the distinction in fine isn't subtle and is odd in that sense.

Comment: *Another Fine Mess* and *a fine kettle of fish* are both phrases using *fine* sarcastically. The meaning of *fine* itself doesn't change. The sarcastic construction is what flips it on its head.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't seem to have awarded me a "Diehard Brit" hat yet, but rest assured I'm wearing one in spirit when I say I think OP has stumbled upon a [very interesting](http://i.imgur.com/eyJNd.png) aspect of how Anglophones use the word ***fine***.

Comment: thx @FumbleFingers I feel like I asked a really unwanted question (my first here nonetheless). I don't understand some of the comments or downvotes to be honest.

Comment: @timpone: Well, that first comment from Kris accurately summarises the basic point (practically *all* common words have multiple meanings that can vary according to context). And relatively speaking, the difference between *fine=good* and *fine=acceptable* is bordering on a [fine distinction](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fine+distinction%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Incidentally, I'm pretty sure numismatists consider a coin in "fine" condition to be better than one that's merely "very good". And *that* usage isn't "sarcastic", so far as I know.

Comment: Thx @FumbleFingers My point re fine was that **in the same context**, it has two different meanings which is not the point that common words have multiple meanings that can vary according to context. The distinction, at least in the states, isn't between good and acceptable but more between very good, great, refined, exemplary vs acceptable. Perhaps it's just a California thing. Oh well, I appreciate your comment and sorry if I sound grumpy.

Comment: @timpone: You don't sound grumpy to me, but by the same token I'm sorry if I sound dismissive. My point is that (superficially, at least) the question obviously puts us in mind of "meaning reversal" usages - which are so common in English there'll be no shortage of people able and willing to illustrate that point by actually *using* the technique. I'd also point out that in *"You don't love me? Fine! I'll marry someone else!"* you could probably make a case for saying *"Fine!" = "Fuck you, then!"*. But in the final analysis, *fine* and *good* aren't really fixed points on a "quality scale".

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the difference you are identifying is a fine (no pun intended) shade of degree. That kind of distinction could be made of almost any adjective. If I say, "This coffee tastes good" in a flat, matter of fact voice, that would be a mild positive. But "Wow, this coffee tastes good!!!" in an excited tone of voice would be a large positive. Indeed, in your example, drop the "very" and the same situation exists for the word "good". "You used good examples in this paper" could mean anywhere from barely adequate to the greatest in the history of paper-writing.

There are some words in English that are much stranger than that. Like "cleave" can mean "to cut in half" or also "to stick together", which are pretty much opposites.

Comment: cleave is a great one. I think what's odd about fine is that the word is a value word and it has two different meanings. I kinda disagree with your point about good. That's the middle. Most time I see fine used as a value statement it's either as 'acceptable' or 'very good'. Prob more of a peave than a real question. Thx for answer - sorry if I wasted your time.